# How to Move Lucene Index results into SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, lucene

I have a little over 1 million records in my lucene database and would like to move them into a new database so I can more easily do advanced searching and join it with my existing tables etc.  I have done some searching and haven't found a good/fast way to take my existing lucene database files and move them into a sql database.

Any help would be appreciated or pointing me in the right direction.

Details: My sql database is Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. My application which creates the lucene database is a web scraper writing in c#

EDIT: I am using Lucene.net

Comment: How complex is the lucene db? Number of tables?

Comment: As far as I know there are 12 fields which are inserted into the lucene database.  The number of tables I need to create depends on how many I need to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the answer you're looking for, but I'd just like to point out that an index and a relational database are two vastly different things. Unless you're storing all the data in the index as well, I really don't think what you're trying to do is possible.

Comment: I understand that they are very different things but wondering if there is a way to structure a request of some sort to move my current Lucene index into a database structure

Comment: @bvandrunen: are you storing the data in the index as well? I know with Lucene you have the ability to do that (although I would advise against it). If you do have all the data stored in the index as well, then you can do what you want, if not, then what you're asking for is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Putting your Lucene index in DB negates the purpose of indexing. The main advantage of Lucene is extremely fast, relevant searches over huge amount of text. Instead of putting index into the DB you might as well just use MSSQL Server full text search instead.
I think you should consider your requirements once again and either switch to MSSQL full text search or use standard Lucene searching mechanisms.